# iPhone alarm clock progressive music alert + volume control

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, volume

I am working on a custom iPhone alarm clock.

Some users have slept in when the device is on silent and locked.

I know that the top iPhone alarms ('Smart Alarm Clock Free', 'Living Earth', 'Rise') can manually control and increase the volume if the App is in the foreground before the user locks their device.

Does anyone know how it is possible to navigate around silent mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When configuring your [audio session](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH1-SW1) simply use the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` category. From the docs:

> AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback or the equivalent kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback—Use this category for an application whose audio playback is of primary importance. Your audio plays even with the screen locked and with the Ring/Silent switch set to silent.

Details about the different audio session categories and how to set them can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Configuration/Configuration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW3).

Comment: if I have questions in the future would you be interested in doing some consultant work? (im a solo developer) thanks

Comment: Perhaps we should continue this discussion through email. My email address is available on my profile, send me details of what you have in mind.

Comment: actually i cant find you email address there?

Comment: This only negates the silent switch.  Volume increase requires the MPMusicPlayerController trick cited elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

it isn't possible. The hardware switch that turns ios to silent mode cant be overriden by ios apps

*(as always jailbreak'd iPhones are excluded :D)*